# API Call problems - JSON (also XML) Android

Tags: android, xml, json, api

I'm trying to learn how to do an API call.  I found some tutorials and adapted the code to suit me but something is wrong.

When I get to result=sb.toString(); I have the following in my string

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /appInfo/getAllApplications. Reason:
<pre>    METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                


</body>
</html>
```

I get the same result if I set my header as application/xml so its not a JSON problem.  I know the URL is right because my browser gets the correct data with the same URL.  I think the problem is somewhere in my BufferedReader but I don't know enough about it yet to figure out what the problem might be.

```
public class APICall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private static Context mCtx;

public APICall(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
    String api = prefs.getString("API", "");
    String url = "http://api.flurry.com/appInfo/getAllApplications?apiAccessCode=" + api;

    //initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //try parse the string to a JSON object
    try{
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }


    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you should be using HttpGet and not HttpPost.

Comment: They are different Http Methods. And as your error was regarding Http Methods it seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're using is POST.  The HTTP application hosting that content is expecting something else - most likely GET.  Apache HTTP Client has a class for that - [HTTPGet](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html)... naturally.
As for the difference between the two.  Well the main difference is that the GET method encodes paramaters as part of the URL (for example you may notice ?apiAccessCode=api&parameter2=something), whereas POST puts the content as part of the HTTP message body.  HTTP GET is limited as well to 256 characters.  Also the use cases are meant to be different.  HTTP GET should be used for data retrieval only, and HTTP Post can be used for updating content.  Now these are merely use cases and aren't always followed.  You actually could update content with a get request.
HTH